# Losing bloc state on orientation change

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, bloc, adaptive-design

I am trying to make my Flutter mobile app responsive and adaptive.

I am using this widget to accomplish this:

```
class ExamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExamplePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DeviceSpecificLayout(
        mobilePortrait: ExampleMobilePortrait(),
        mobileLandscape: ExampleMobileLandscape(),
        tabletPortrait: ExampleTabletPortrait(),
        tabletLandscape: ExampleTabletLandscape(),
    );
  }
}
```

The DeviceSpecificLayout widget:

```
class DeviceSpecificLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobilePortrait;
  final Widget mobileLandscape;
  final Widget tabletPortrait;
  final Widget tabletLandscape;

  const DeviceSpecificLayout({
    super.key,
    required this.mobilePortrait,
    required this.mobileLandscape,
    required this.tabletPortrait,
    required this.tabletLandscape,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenTypeLayout.builder(
      mobile: (context) => OrientationLayoutBuilder(
        portrait: (context) => mobilePortrait,
        landscape: (context) => mobileLandscape,
      ),
      tablet: (context) => OrientationLayoutBuilder(
        portrait: (context) => tabletPortrait,
        landscape: (context) => tabletLandscape,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue I am encountering is that whenever the app changes orientation my bloc's state is completely lost because of the build when the app switches the orientation.

This is my main.dart, I am using MultiBlocProvider.

```
      runApp(
        MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(create: (_) => ExampleBloc1()),
            BlocProvider(create: (_) => ExampleBloc2()),
          ],
          child: ExamplePage(),
        ),
      );
```

This is the widget that loses it's state on orientation change:

```
SafeArea(
                              child: BlocBuilder<ExampleBloc, ExampleState>(
                                builder: (context, state) {
                                  return state.exampleVariable == false
                                      ? Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                          child: CountDownAnimatedText(
                                            animation: StepTween(begin: 120, end: 0).animate(animationController),
                                            countdownFontSize: 30.0,
                                            instructionTextFontSize: 25.0,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Container();
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
```

The above widget is a countdown, which on state orientation loses the countdown state and resets at the beginning.

I am also using the https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_builder package.

Maybe I am approaching the responsiveness and adaptiveness of the app wrong.

I'd love any comments on this.

Comment: and how or where are you listening to your blocs and what change you see?

Comment: I have provided the widget that is losing its state in my explanation above, I'd love it if you could take a look! I am using BlocBuilder.

Comment: I'm not sure is your bloc what is resetting but your StepTween that is being created again in the build method

Comment: or maybe the way you start the controller, you mean that wehn you change orientation the widget becomes the container? (exampleVariable  == true)

Comment: and your state only change in one callback or you have multiple logic where it could cahnge?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your UI has a drastic change (like orientation, in mobile orientating the screen equals to change the size of it just like in browsers/desktop apps you can resize your window) it force to call all build methods to change whatever is different, that's mostly your logic with `ScreenTypeLayout` and `OrientationLayoutBuilder` but also all objects created inside the build method (like your `mobilePortrait` or `mobileLandscape`). If each widget creates a controller when one is disposed and the other created the animation will seems to restart:

```
 ///Have your animation controller created in one initState or hook and avoid create it in the widgets that will be disposed/changed in the widget tree

BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state.exampleVariable) {
      animationController.forward(from: 0);
    } else {
      animationController.value = 0; ///reset
    }
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    return state.exampleVariable == false
       ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          child: CountDownAnimatedText(
          animation: StepTween(begin: 120, end: 0).animate(animationController),
          countdownFontSize: 30.0,
          instructionTextFontSize: 25.0,
        ),
      )
    : Container();
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to answer, It turns out my issue had nothing to do with the bloc's state, but anyway, I appreciate the answer!